# How can we handle users who use Single sign on but then also use the same email to register a normal account? Multi part (UX) question

Tags: authentication, web, frontend, registration, user-experience

So we are planning to add SSO to our website however there are some questions that remain challenging to answer and I hope someone on here can help with this.
Note: We are planning to use Google, Apple Facebook and Linkedin as the SSO options for our users

Q1 - If a user who has not previously created an account goes to the login form and then selects a SSO option, will this trigger an error asking them the account does not exist or will the SSO login  just create an account in the background making it seamless as if the user has logged in?

Q2 - How can we handle duplicate accounts? I imagine is some cases we may get users who will signup using SSO and later the same user may attempt to create an account manually (email/password). Will it be up to us to have some kind of error catch in place.
For example, if I used Google SSO and it signed me up as example@googlemail.com, I later then come back and create a account manually using example@gmail.com Is there a way we can stop these users from creating duplicate accounts?

Potential solution for Q2, we may treat the email pre-fix e.g. @googlemail.com and @gmail.com as the same email to prevent duplicate accounts.